# Bind checkbox to element of one array in Ember 2+

Tags: javascript, ember.js, checkbox, ember-data, ember.js-2

I'm trying to bind elements of one array to the checked attribute of checkboxes using Ember 2.8. I'm also using this in one component.

The checkboxes show all marked, but whenever I tried to use the action `hideOrShowAllColumns` it does not mark all checkboxes again if there was one which was not checked... so I guess I'm passing the value of the array element and not the element itself. I don't know how to do this in javascript/ember...

This is my view

```
{{input type="checkbox" name="all" checked=allColumnsChecked change=(action "hideOrShowAllColumns")}} 
All
{{#each model_table.columns as |column index|}}
    {{input type="checkbox" name=column checked=(getItemAt allColumns index) change=(action "hideOrShowColumn" index)}}
    {{column}}
{{/each}}
```

This is my component.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.set('allColumnsChecked', true);
    },
    didReceiveAttrs() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        let columnMap = this.get('columnMap');
        let allColumns = Array(columnMap.length).fill(true);
        this.set('allColumns', allColumns);
    },
    actions: {
         hideOrShowAllColumns() {
            let all = this.get('allColumnsChecked');
            all = !all;
            this.set('allColumnsChecked', all);
            if (all === true) {
                let allColumns = this.get('allColumns');
                allColumns = allColumns.map(() =>  true);
                this.set('allColumns', allColumns);
            }
        },
}
```

Helper getItemAt

```
export function getItemAt(params) {
    return params[0][params[1]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two-way binding you can't use primitive type.`checked=(getItemAt allColumns index)` this part won't workout. it will not update `allColumns` array values when you checked checkbox.
So I would recommend you to have `model_table.columns` in this array of column you can have checked property and you can use it in input helper.

First, `model_table.columns` should be an array of objects.

```
model_table.columns = [
    {
       'name': 'foo',
       'checked': true
    },
    {
       'name': 'bar',
       'checked': true
    }
]
```

Second, use the property in the htmlbar

```
{{#each model_table.columns as |column index|}}
    {{input type="checkbox" name=column.name checked=column.checked change=(action "hideOrShowColumn" index)}}
    {{column.name}}
{{/each}
```

Whenever you update checkbox it will update corresponding column.isChecked property.

To update the corresponding column need to use

```
Ember.set(column, 'checked', true)
```

where column is one element of the `model_table.columns` and checked is its property

Comment: I suspected this could be the reason of the malfunction, but how do I make this function `isChecked` ? my `model_table.columns` has the name of the columns; my var `allColumns` has the checked value of the columns. eg: `model_table.columns = ['id','name']; allColumns = [true, false];`

Comment: Ok, I guess I have one idea. I should make `model_table.columns = [{'name': 'id', 'checked': true}, {'name': 'name', 'checked': true}]`. Let me test...

Comment: Yes. Generate this struture using computed property using allColumns and model_table.columns . `model_table.columns =[{id:1,name:'name1',value:'value1',isChecked:true}] ` and try it out

Comment: I'm getting an error now "Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the `checked` property (of [object Object]) to `false`." I'm using this: `let model_table = this.get('model_table'); let column = model_table['columns'][i]; column['checked'] = false; model_table['columns'][i] = column; this.set('model_table', model_table);`

Comment: try like this `Ember.set('columns','checked',false)`  always use Ember.get and set only then it would be observale.

Comment: I had to use Ember.set(column, 'checked', false) and it worked. I will edit your answer to be according to the real solution and mark as accepted since it lead me to the solution